# Call a client-side function from server-side

Tags: node.js

I am having trouble calling a client-side function from the server-side. I am currently using a file watcher in the server-side. What I want to happen is that when the file is altered, it would trigger a client-side function.

Code from *server-side*

```
const fs = require( `fs` ),
           filewatcher = require('filewatcher');

watcher = filewatcher();
watcher.add(messageBox);
watcher.on('change', function(folder, stat) {
           callThisFunction();
});
```

Code from *client-side*

```
function callThisFunction() {
           //insert code here
}
```

Comment: Probably you have to `socket.io` `emit` event from server side and listen it in client side and execute your function

Answer (score 0):

The actual code doesn't really look like you're calling `callThisFunction` from the backend, look up https://socket.io/docs/ it should help.

What you should be doing is creating a socket and a listener to that socket on your front-end. Once that socket is fired, you can run whatever you want in your client.

**Bad practice**:
Instead of using sockets, you can send a request to the server every second (`setInterval(sendRequest, 1000)`) which checks the backend whether there are updates or not, and you would respond with something like `{ response: { data: { fireThisFunction: true } } }`.
I'm just offering this solution because it's faster and you might find out that you don't even need to fire your function from the backend.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a WebSocket to communicate changes from the server to the client, effectively you can invoke a function on the client using this approach.

Run the server locally, then open index.html in your browser.

**server.js**

```
const WebSocketServer = require("websocket").server;
const http = require("http");
const filewatcher = require("filewatcher");

const server = http.createServer((request, response) => {
});

server.listen(8080, function() {
    console.log("Server is listening on port 8080");
});

webSocketServer = new WebSocketServer({
    httpServer: server,
    autoAcceptConnections: false
});

let webConn = null;
webSocketServer.on("request", function(request) {
    console.log("New Connection...");
    const connection = request.accept("some-protocol", request.origin);
    webConn = connection;
    connection.on("message", function(message) {
        if (message.type === "utf8") {
            console.log("New Message from client:" + message.utf8Data);
        }
    });
});

// Start watching directory..
const watcher = filewatcher();

watcher.add("./watch_dir");
watcher.on("change", function(folder, stat) {
    console.log("file change:", folder, stat);
    if (webConn) {
        webConn.sendUTF(JSON.stringify({ folder, stat}));
    }
});
```

**index.html**

```
<html lang="en">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<head>
    <title>Websocket demo</title>
    <script>
        console.log("Sending hello..")
        const webSocket = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8080/", "some-protocol");
        webSocket.onopen = function (event) {
            webSocket.send("Ping from client.."); 
        };

        webSocket.onmessage = function (event) {
            console.log("Message from server:", event.data);
            callThisFunction(event.data);
        }

        function callThisFunction(data) {
            document.getElementById("output").innerHTML += "<br><li>Message from server:" + (data) + "</li>";
        }

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <ul id="output">
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```